# Programmatic creation of sheets and visuals in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have visual data available to bind in the sheet for example (positions and types of visuals with source data) and I want to update the analysis with my updated sheets/visuals programmatically. Here are a few things I’d like to accomplish by programmatically creating analyses:

- Eliminate Manual Work: Creating Quicksight reports involves a lot of repetitive click-and-drag work. It would be more efficient to replace this with code.
- Improve Re-usability: Re-using content in Quicksight is a very click intensive manual process. Code is easier to reuse for similar work.
- Improve Precision: Click-intensive manual processes are naturally error prone. Giving users the ability to script out analysis creation reduces the potential for error.

Is there any way to create/ Update existing sheets and visuals programmatically?

Any quicksight api endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonably rich API for dealing with quicksight. You can programmatically create an analysis https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAnalysis.html

You can also use the aws command line interface (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to create dashboards and analyses as well.